# AIX: Why does throwing an exception abort multithreaded code?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, aix

We get an abort when a C++ exception is thrown when running code compiled with -pthread.

Platform: AIX 5.3 technical level 8
Compiler: gcc 3.4.6
Linker: AIX linker 1.65.2.4

Test Code:

```
// exception.cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyException
{
public:
        MyException(){}
        virtual ~MyException(){};
};

void gTest()
{
        throw MyException();
}

int main()
{
        try
        {
                gTest();
        }
        catch(MyException const & ex)
        {
                std::cout << "exception was caught" << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
}


$ g++ exception.cpp
$ ./a.out
exception was caught
$ g++ -pthread exception.cpp
$ ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException'
IOT/Abort trap (core dumped)
$ gdb a.out
GNU gdb 6.0
Copyright 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB. Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0"...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/leeder/except/a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException'

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
Switching to Thread 1
0xd0124834 in pthread_kill () from /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
(gdb) bt
#0 0xd0124834 in pthread_kill () from /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
#1 0xd01242a8 in _p_raise () from /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
#2 0xd0359bdc in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
#3 0xd03b7efc in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
#4 0xd0ca1800 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:96
#5 0xd0ca1220 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) (handler=0)
at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:43
#6 0xd0ca128c in std::terminate() () at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:53
#7 0xd0ca7cfc in __cxa_throw (obj=0x200084e8, tinfo=0xffffffff, dest=Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff
)
at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:80
#8 0x100008dc in gTest() ()
#9 0x100009f0 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Do you think upgrading to gcc 4 would help?

What about switching to IBM's xl compiler?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds weird...have you tried any other compilers?

Comment: We're going to try gcc 4.3.2, but I wanted to see if anyone else had any experience.

Comment: Works on AIX 6100-06 and 7100-01 with g++ 4.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g++ 4.3.2 seems to work Ok for this problem. Also xlC v10 works.

Answer (score 2):

Tried your program on AIX:

> oslevel -r
>
> 5200-08

with g++ --version

> g++ (GCC) 3.3.2
>
> g++ -o ex -pthread ex.cpp

will result in symbols not found at runtime (pthread_mutex_t)

However if you build it like:

> g++ -o ex -lpthread ex.cpp

works just fine with expected effects.
I guess this might be a link problem with right pthread libraries.